# addressing asset stylesheets with file extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some stylesheets in a subfolder /app/assets/stylesheets/themes of my rails app. These assets have the file extension .css.scss extension.

In my development environment I've been addressing those files with:

```
 asset_path 'themes/theme-name.css.scss'
```

However, when I go to production Rails won't find those files. When I use just .css extension it seems to be working okay:

```
asset_path 'theme/theme-name.css'
```

My question is: what is the correct way to address asset files with multiple extensions?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way should be:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'themes/theme-name'
```

If Rails is configured correct, the assets pipeline will figure out the file extensions itself .

Comment: How to get just the stylesheet link path instead of the whole tag?

Comment: @Aljaz use `asset_path 'themes/theme-name` to get the url for the asset. More info can be found in the [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sass loaded in your Gemfile?